# VueJS / VueFire : data empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm working on a project with vuejs and i'm having problem to get
data from Firebase with vuefire.
here's the code :

Firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import Vue from 'vue'

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXXXXXX"
  };

  
  // Initialize Firebase
export const app =  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
Vue.config.productionTip = false

 export const db = app.database();
```

export const reviewsRef = db.ref("reviews");

This is the component where i want the data

```
import { db } from '../firebase';
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            // liste des review de cet utilisateur
            reviews:[],
            userUid:'',
            // review a afficher dans le detail
            reviewToDisplay:null
        }
    },
    firebase:{
        reviews: db.ref("reviews")
    }
```

when i try just to display the reviews it's just an empty array... i really don't know why it doesn't work.

My firebase tree structure
[image: screenshot image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning firebase, myself. But, FWIW:

From https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

> Before 8.0.0
>
> import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
>
> After 8.0.0
>
> import firebase from 'firebase/app'

A sample app from SinghDigamber, using firebase 7.13.2,
@ https://github.com/SinghDigamber/vue-firebase-setup/blob/master/src/firebaseDatabase.js

shows:

> import * as firebase from 'firebase';

(i.e., without '/app') So, you should try:

> import * as firebase from 'firebase'

as your firebase version is < 8.0.0

Comment: Don't forget to import `firebase/database`